# JavaScript: How to add an id to all links at the end

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a list of inputs with specific IDs. When I fill them out and press a button the info that I type in gets transferred to a template and fill in all specific areas.

Here is a small sample of JavaScript that I have on the end with form inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="MyID" value="">
function .....
{ id: 'MyID', src: myform.MyID.value },
```

Then it goes through JS:

```
for ( i=0; i< myLinks.length; i++)
    {
        if (template.getElementById(myLinks[i].id)==null)
        {
        continue;
        }
        template.getElementById(myLinks[i].id).href=(myLinks[i].href);
    }
```

Then it fill in specific divs or spans that have identical ids.

QUESTION:
I will need to add one more input and what will go in there should appear at the end of each url that my template has.

example: id : in a new input I type ~122

template: `<a href="Link ' and it adds ' ~122"></a>`

Can I modify this template.getElementById(myLinks[i].id).href=(myLinks[i].href); somehow and add something to it so it add my new id input to all links at the end?

Hopefully it is not confusing and thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, it is pretty confusing, giving up parsing the question

Answer (score 0):

You can combine strings using the `+` operator so you could technically do `(myLinks[i].href+"122")`

Comment: Hello, thank you for an answer. How can I include specific id value of input? I tried document.getElementById("nid") but it gave me [object HTMLInputElement] at the end instead of the value I had in the input. Thank you.

Comment: @Artem I think you want `myLinks[i].href+document.getElementById("nid").value`

Comment: Got it!:::::: => (myLinks[i].href+ document.getElementById("nid").value)